# App crashing when fail to load data using Rxjava 2 and Retrofit 2

Tags: android, heroku, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using retrofit2 and rxjava2 as a networking library in my app.Sometimes when app fail to load data from server in activity it crashes.I am fai to understand why it is happening.

This is my code below:

**ApiService.java**

```
public interface ApiService {

@POST("retrofitUsers")
@FormUrlEncoded
Observable<String> saveData(@Field("name") String name,
                         @Field("age") String age);

@GET("getUsers")
Observable<List<BioData>> getData();

}
```

**RetrofitClient.java**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getInstance(){

    if(retrofit == null)
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://bookbudiapp.herokuapp.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

    return retrofit;

}

private RetrofitClient(){

}
}
```

**BioData.java**

```
public class BioData {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
private String age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

    recycle = findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    recycle.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    list  = new ArrayList<>();

    compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    fetchData();
}

    private void fetchData(){

    Retrofit retrofit  = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    ApiService myApi = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    Disposable disposable = myApi.getData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                           .subscribe(new Consumer<List<BioData>>() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void accept(List<BioData> bioData) throws Exception {

                                                   adapter = new UserAdapter(bioData,getApplicationContext());
                                                   recycle.setAdapter(adapter);
                                               }
                                           });



    compositeDisposable.add(disposable);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

   compositeDisposable.clear();

}
}
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Can you add the stack trace ?

Comment: It does not crash normally but when I open it after a long time It crashes while fetching data from server.

Comment: It seems it may be a time out problem.

Comment: post error log here.

Comment: Could you please tell how can I add time out for read and write operation.

Comment: As DHAVALASODARIYA requested, you should post the crash log to find the root cause, in addition to @Skizo-ozᴉʞS improvement, that helps to mitigate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced the same issue days ago until I found this [`Free Dyno Hours`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours), where explains :

> Every Heroku account is allocated a pool of free dyno hours. An app actively consumes free dyno hours if the app is set to use free dynos and any of the following are true:
>
> It has a web dyno that is receiving traffic (i.e., not sleeping)
>
> It has a worker dyno running
>
> It has a one-off dyno running. For example, one started via the CLI or Scheduler.

What does it means? If you are using a `Free account` and you stay a while without doing any call to your `Heroku` web-server it will sleep, and once you call it again,it won't be awake.

For more information, read the [`Heroku Dynos`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos)

What I did is, create an `OkHttpClient` as follows :

```
private fun makeOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
}
```

And then in your `Retrofit` builder just add `.client(makeOkHttpClient())` so you can assign a `readTimeout` and `writeTimeout`.

Also I recommend to you to use instead of `CompositeDisposable` use a `Disposable` since you only have one call, so you can avoid the `.add()` thingy.

Comment: Where should I make this OkHttpClient builder.

Comment: In addition to this solution for the specific issue that the server has to be restarted, the code should properly handle the timeout without crashing the app (e.g. when bad network, etc.)

Comment: @Digvijay Inside your RetrofitClient you can add this method

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana that's the purpose of `OkHttpClient` and `timeOut`

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS,please when I am making method like you in retrofitclient it is showing error.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS No, this will just increment the timeout. But if you're in a bad network connection the timeout will be reached eventually, and the app will also crash.